# Output of two tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, lag, lead

I'm learning SQL and I came across the below-mentioned scenario.

```
Table 1
id  Name City
1   Ryan Chennai
2   Tom  Banglore
3   Sam  Pune
4   Kat  Mumbai

Table 2
id month salary
1  prev  1000
1  cur   4000
1  next  3000
2  prev  1000
2  cur   3000
2  next  4000
3  prev  2000
3  cur   5000
3  next  6000
4  prev  1500
4  cur   2500
4  next  3000
```

Output table should look like this

```
id  name city      cur  prev next
1   Ryan Chennai   4000 1000 3000
2
3
4
```

(Similarly for other ids as well.)

So what are the different ways to achieve this and also it would be very helpful if someone helps me to understand how to approach these kinds of problems.

Comment: You really don't need to use Lead or lag. This can be done using three SUM(CASE...) statements and a group by.

Comment: Why are all but one of the rows empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we create the data.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_2;

CREATE TABLE table_1 (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name VARCHAR(10),
  City VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE table_2 (
    id INT,
    month VARCHAR(10),
    salary INT);

INSERT INTO table_1
VALUES (1, 'Ryan', 'Chennai'),
       (2, 'Tom', 'Banglore'),
       (3, 'Sam', 'Pune'),
       (4, 'Kat', 'Mumbai');

INSERT INTO table_2
VALUES (1, 'prev', 1000),
       (1, 'cur', 4000),
       (1, 'next', 3000),
       (2, 'prev', 1000),
       (2, 'cur', 3000),
       (2, 'next', 4000),
       (3, 'prev', 2000),
       (3, 'cur', 5000),
       (3, 'next', 6000),
       (4, 'prev', 1500),
       (4, 'cur', 2500),
       (4, 'next', 3000);
```

In order to achieve the desired result, we `join` the tables on the `id` column and `sum` over the `month` column, taking only the values into account which are needed, respectively.

```
SELECT t1.name
     , t1.city
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t2.month = 'cur' THEN salary ELSE 0 END) AS 'cur'
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t2.month = 'prev' THEN salary ELSE 0 END) AS 'prev'
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t2.month = 'next' THEN salary ELSE 0 END) AS 'next'
  FROM table_1 AS t1
       INNER JOIN table_2 AS t2 
                  USING (id)
 GROUP BY t1.name, t1.city;
```

We obtain the following table:

| name | city | cur | prev | next |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ryan | Chennai | 4000 | 1000 | 3000 |
| Tom | Banglore | 3000 | 1000 | 4000 |
| Sam | Pune | 5000 | 2000 | 6000 |
| Kat | Mumbai | 2500 | 1500 | 3000 |